# Find out Default Application for Mime types in android

Tags: android, settings, default, mime-types

How to get default applications set by users in android through code?
I know we can get the default application's package name through packageManager for a particular MIME type.
But is there a way to get a list of all the applications registered as default for opening various files?

Comment: in short i want a this kind of list 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zealdroid.cleardefaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [PackageManager.getPreferredActivities()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPreferredActivities%28java.util.List%3Candroid.content.IntentFilter%3E,%20java.util.List%3Candroid.content.ComponentName%3E,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
    final PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();

    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<IntentFilter> outFilters = new ArrayList<IntentFilter>();
    outFilters.add(filter);

    List<ComponentName> outActivities = new ArrayList<ComponentName>();
    pm.getPreferredActivities(outFilters, outActivities, null);
```

Comment: thnx! Exactly what i wanted!

Comment: Can I get the MIME type for which the application is made the Launcher from the intentfilter?
Without iterating over the list ouactivities and finding out from the package name?